# How to short dataframe data's names

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataFrame which first index is A, like this:

```
A

"ABCDEF"

"BNDLSSL:SHKSJD:SKLAAS:ASSDAS"

"SSMDLL"

"KSDKDL:AHSMSD:MSSML"

"NSMSDKKD"

"SMDDLDW"

"NSNSJDJSK:SMSKKSS"
```

I want to remove ":" expression , just it must write until ":"

for example i want to this output:

```
  A

"ABCDEF"

"BNDLSSL"

"SSMDLL"

"KSDKDL"

"NSMSDKKD"

"SMDDLDW"

"NSNSJDJSK"
```

I wrote this code but it works just one index, I want to all of dataFrame(df)

```
df.iloc[1,0].split(":")[0]
```

Comment: `df.A.str.split(':').str[0]`

Comment: ditch the `iloc` and use the `expand=True` argument `df['A'].str.split(':',expand=True)[0]`